# How to disable ask password "Please unlock dis sda3_crypt" when turn on my PC?

Tags: 14.04

**How to disable ask password "Please unlock dis sda3_crypt"** when turn on my PC? I'm annoyed to always have to enter the password when opening my laptop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decrypt LUKS partition without losing data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035777/decrypt-luks-partition-without-losing-data)

Comment: Thank you. I will try it